# Why is disabled attribute set to disabled in Vue 2.0

Tags: javascript, vue.js

According to Vue documentation, in order to disable an element (e.g. a button) dynamically, I used `:disabled="myVar"`, so my code is something like the following:

```
<button type="button" class="btn text-primary float-right" @click="buttonClicked" :disabled="!buttonEnabled">Click Me!</button>
```

I expected it to render as:

```
<button type="button" .... disabled>Click Me!</button>
```

However, when rendered, the disabled attribute was set to "disabled":

```
<button type="button" ... disabled="disabled">Click Me!</button>
```

While it works fine, I would like to know if there is a reason for disabled attribute to have the disabled value, and if it is possible to change.

Comment: Probably to support browsers. Some older browsers I presume require attributes to have values to them

Comment: For html5 both `disabled="disabled"` and `disabled` are valid.

Comment: @t.niese I must say that as far as I checked, any value set is valid (e.g. disabled="stuff") not just disabled="disabled" or disabled

Comment: No, the html5 specs define a [Boolean attributes](https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/common-microsyntaxes.html#boolean-attribute) as `[...]Its value must either be the empty string or a value that is an ASCII case-insensitive match for the attribute's canonical name, with no leading or trailing whitespace.[...]` so `disabled="stuff"` is not valid. So the only valid usages are `disabled`, `disabled="disabled"` and `disabled=""`

Comment: I agree is defined like that, I'm just pointing out that using a chrome browser for example, `disabled="stuff"` works (https://jsfiddle.net/t8b7vdqn/)

Comment: That the browser accepts the value does not mean that it is **valid** do that. Whether you can assume that the invalid value has the same result as the valid value, depends on how the standard defines the error correction in this case and whether it is actually implement in the browser. But that does not change the fact the `disabled="stuff"` is not valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In XHTML, attribute minimization is forbidden, and the disabled
>   attribute must be defined as <input disabled="disabled" />.

Taken from:
https://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/att_input_disabled.asp

Comment: Having a site set to `xhtml` is really uncommon these days. To have latest features and to make sure that all browsers behave the same way you use html5, and for html5 both `disabled="disabled"` and `disabled` valid.